# How to tell Swift which function signature to use between default optionals

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit, ios13

I want to instantiate the root view controller of a Storyboard I created.

To do so I was used to calling `-instantiateInitialViewController()` from a storyboard.

The thing is since iOS13 there’s a new method signature that takes a new optional argument: `(creator: ((NSCoder)->ViewController?)?)`

[image: Capture of Xcode showing autocompletion]

The annoying thing is that Xcode thinks I want to use that new API, which makes my app incompatible with older OS.

[image: Capture of Xcode showing an inline error prompt]

And I can’t get around it, even with a version check.

[image: Capture of Xcode still showing an error after applying a suggested fix]

My question is: **How to tell the compiler to use the method signature without the parameter?**

Comment: Try deleting your derived data. I just created a new project with compatibility to iOS 10 and the line is perfectly-recognized by Xcode (Version 11.5)

Comment: Hey, regardless of the Xcode bug, I have answered your bolded question **How to tell the compiler to use which method signature** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63504077/5623035). Did you check that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>**Quick Answer for your issue: Xcode BUG**</sub>

<sub>First of all, as your screenshots show, it's a bug. (try removing driven data or restarting stuff to make it work). The following is the answer to your question.</sub>

---

## Explanation: How to tell the compiler to use which method signature

Swift infers the function signature based on the used Types in the expression. So imagine this:

```
class ViewController { }
class UIViewController { }

func instantiateInitialViewController() -> UIViewController? {}
func instantiateInitialViewController() -> ViewController? {}
```

So calling this would be *ambiguous use of `instantiateInitialViewController()`*:

```
let theController = instantiateInitialViewController()
```

The solution for this is to **tell** the compiler what is the expected type explicitly:

```
let theController: ViewController? = instantiateInitialViewController()
let theOtherController: UIViewController? = instantiateInitialViewController()
```

---

The new `instantiateInitialViewController` return type is a protocol (`ViewController`) that constrained to `UIViewController`. So it should infer the type and have no logical difference from the old one. So just keep calm and just let it infer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Ok this became patently a bug from Xcode.

After restarting my mac, it works fine.

Why did I thought the error could came from me… ‍♀️

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I don't know the answer on your question, but maybe you just want to init your ViewController from Storyboard for iOS version less than 13.0? Try this:

```
UIStoryboard(name: "storyboardName", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerID")
```

Comment: I already tried it and unfortunately there’s the optional parameter on that signature too.

Comment: Did you try to unwrap your instantiateViewController result ?
guard let myVC = UIStoryboard(name: "storyboardName", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerID") as? MyViewController else { return UIViewController() }

or you also can use 'as!'

Answer (score 0):

UIViewController objects can be saved to disk and restored upon request (ie, battery down, memory warning issues).

The new iOS13 method

```
instantiateInitialViewController { (coder:NSCoder) -> MyViewController? in
    return MyViewController(coder: coder)
}
```

allows the view controller instance come to life by restoring some of its state.

This method call invokes initWith(coder:) in MyViewController, where one can, in this example, restore "name" property.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
      
    var name:String?
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        name = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as? String
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }   
}
```